# SQLAlchemy 2 Foreign Keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

New to Flask/SQLAlchemy and can't figure out how to architect this one-to-many db. I have two tables (1) `Miles` the distances between all airport combinations and (2) `FlightHistory` which contains a record for each `user_id`'s flight.

I'd like to be able to query for total mileage by `FlightHistory.user_id`.

```python
class Miles(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    orig = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=False)
    dest = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=False)
    miles = db.Column(db.Integer, index=False, unique=False)

class FlightHistory(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, unique=False)
    orig = db.Column(db.String(64), index=False, unique=False)
    dest = db.Column(db.String(64), index=False, unique=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, index=False, unique=False)
```

I tried adding `trips = db.relationship('FlightHistory', backref='flyer', lazy='dynamic')` to `Miles` and adding `miles = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(['miles.orig', 'miles.dest']))` to `FlightHistory`.

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

```
class Miles(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    orig = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=False)
    dest = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=False)
    miles = db.Column(db.Integer, index=False, unique=False)
    trip_id = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('flight_histories.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    trip = relationship("FlightHistory", foreign_keys=[trip_id])

class FlightHistory(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "flight_histories"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, unique=False)
    orig = db.Column(db.String(64), index=False, unique=False)
    dest = db.Column(db.String(64), index=False, unique=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, index=False, unique=False)
    miles = relationship("Miles", cascade="all,delete",
                           foreign_keys=[Miles.trip_id])
```